# How to store character in array one after another untill user enters input other than character, and then reproduce the same on the screen?

Tags: c, arrays, char

Below is the program that i m using a to store a-z alphabets from users and then reproduce the same on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int const size = 26;
    int index;
    char arr[size];   // = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    printf("\nEnter the lowercase letters\n");
    for (index = 0; index < size; index++){
        scanf_s("%c", &arr[index]);
    }

    for (index = 0; index < size; index++){
        printf("\n%c\n", arr[index]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Although, it is easier for me to store it directly and then reproduce it but whenever i start running the program. It accepts till letter 'm' and then exits out. I have been trying to figure out but could not find the mistake. Also i m using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Also i m entering the input one line after another.

Comment: to fetch a single character from `stdin` you can do it a lot better with `fgetc(stdin)`.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks this is my beginning. I m learning from stephen pratas book. So far i hv only come to know this way. So can you help me with a short example , just a line on how to use stdin( I m hoping stdin is an header file ie #include<stdin.h>).

Comment: `stdin` is a file stream, didn't the book mention that?

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf_s("%c", &arr[index]);'  1) always check the returned value to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  2) need to check that the user actually input a lower case printable character.   perhaps by: #include <ctype.h> isalpha() islower()  3) should check that the char is not already in the arr[].  4) never assume the user entered the right thing

Comment: suggest reading the 'man' page for each system function that you want to use.  A quick 'google' online using a search term like: 'syntax for function <functionHere> in C' will find you one or more pages that fully describe the function

Comment: @iharob: Its in the upcoming chapter i checked out in index. But i iwll check it out , thanks .

Comment: @user3629249: Pehaps your right i didnt though of using ctype.h.

Comment: @iharob: I tried with this but it only accepts til 26 input. However after that it does not reproduce. Where m i doing wrong. Below is the code

 int index;
 char arr[27]; //= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 
 printf("\nEnter the lowercase letters\n");
 for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
 {
  scanf_s(" %c", &arr[index]);
  _getch();
 }
 printf("\nThanks"); 
 for (index = 0; index < size; ++index)
 {
  printf(" %c ", arr[index]);
 }

Comment: @Ricky try with `scanf()` and not `scanf_s()` since there might be a difference but I don't know because I don't use Windows and therefore I can't test the code with the `MSVC` compiler.

Comment: @iharob: Yes i hv got turboC too, so if sometimes MSVC doesnt work then i try turboC. Result sometimes differ. But i eventually figure out why. And when i dont i hv you guys. I didnt thought about return value of scanf() to assure the input/conversion operation was successful. But this method seems more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `"%c"` specifier is capturing the `'\n'` character left by the previous call.

You can solve it by making the format string ignore that character. That is done by adding a explcit white space before the `%c` like this

```
scanf(" %c", &arr[index]);
```

but in this case it would work a lot better if you simple use `getchar()` or `fgetc()`, like this

```
size_t size = 26;
int    chr;
size_t index;
char   arr[size] = {0};

chr = getchar();
for (index = 0 ; ((index < size) && (chr != EOF)) ; ++index)
 {
    arr[index] = chr;
    chr        = getchar();
 }
for (index = 0 ; index < size ; ++index)
    printf("%c\n", arr[index]);
```

also, you are as apparently everyone else using `scanf()` in the wrong way, even if in this case it's very unlikely that something will go wrong, you don't check for the return value of `scanf()` and that's a potential problem, because if <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or "<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> (Windows OS)", is entered then `arr[index]` would be uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks that did clear the confusion. The first stmt did worked for me. using " %c". Although the second method is a little bit difficult to understand but i m going to try both methods and check the output and figure out how it works. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it